# Getting current product attribute pa_color

Tags: php

When a user selects a color from a drop-down box on the product page I would like to retrieve that selected color attribute or term to use in a table I’m building.  I can get a list of all the colors (red, black, blue, green) for the individual product on the product page using the code listed below but I only want the currently selected color.

Example: if a user selects red I would like the $term-> name “red” to use in my PHP code and not all the colors associated with that product. I've tried get_term, get_term_by, has_term, etc.

```
 $terms =  get_the_terms($product->id,'pa_color' );
 foreach( $terms as $term ) { 
 echo "<option>" . $term->name . "</option>";}
```

Comment: Can anybody help? I would appreciate any help I can get to this question?